# Rの2重xapply()をvimで綺麗に整形する方法が知りたいです

Tags: vim, r

`vim`で`R`を書くのに`vim-scripts/Vim-R-plugin`を利用しています。しかし、

```
sapply(dfs, function(df) {
  sapply(1:5, function(i) {
    do.something(df, i)
  })
})
```

というコードがあったとして(あくまで例なので「`do.something`に1:5をベクトルで渡せば」という話は脇に置いてください)、`vim`でインデントしようとすると

```
sapply(dfs, function(df) {
  sapply(1:5, function(i) {
    do.something(df, i)
})
})
```

のように内側の閉じ括弧が行頭に来てしまいます。内側のfunctionを改行すると、閉じ括弧の問題は解消しますが、個人的にはfunctionで改行したくはありません。

```
sapply(dfs, function(df) {
  sapply(1:5, 
    function(i) {
      do.something(df, i)
    })
})
```

`R`を`vim`から触っている方も多いとは思いますが、どのように解決しているのでしょうか。別のプラグインを使う、設定が間違っているなど、ご教示いただければと思います。

---

役に立つ情報かわかりませんが、関連する`.vimrc`の設定は以下のとおりです。(主にアロー演算子にまつわる問題を回避するための設定)

これらをコメントアウトしても現象は改善しません。

```
let r_indent_align_args = 0
let r_indent_ess_comments = 0
let r_indent_ess_compatible = 0
let vimrplugin_assign = 0
```

尚、`Vim-R-plugin`を使わない場合も閉じ括弧の問題は解決せず、さらにインデントがおかしくなります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rはあまり詳しくないですが、formatRが使えるみたいです。

formatRを先にインストールしておいて:

```
> install.packages("formatR")
```

.vimrcに以下のように記述します:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.R setl ep=r\ -s\ -e\ 'library(formatR);tidy_source(text=readLines(file(\"stdin\")))'
```

ファイルを開いて`gg=G`すれば整形できます。プラグインは、はずしましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.R setl ep=R\ -s\ -e\ 'library(formatR);suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(tidy_source(indent=2,text=readLines(file(\"stdin\")))))'`とすることで、動作できることを確認しました。
整形後に`Please ENTER..`と出るのを抑制できれば、この方法で問題なさそうです。

Comment: @3100, あれ、こちらでは再現しませんでした(OSX Yosemite + Teaminal)。環境を教えてもらえますか？

Comment: ArchにSSH接続してその中でtmuxを立ち上げています(Vim 7.4.335)。が、OSXでは出ないとのことなので帰ったらOSXでも確認してみようと思います。-> 試しにArchでtmuxを立ち上げずにvimを利用したところ、メッセージが表示されませんでした。tmuxの設定の問題かもしれません。ありがとうございます！

Comment: OSX Yosemiteでtmuxを立ち上げている状態から正しく動作することを確認しました。suppressMessages(), suppressWarnings()も不要でした。